# Add step dynamic for ASP.NET Wizard control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to add steps dynamic in Wizard controls and keep the current state?
I use the code below to add a step, it's ok. But after I click other step and postback, this step gone again.

```
WizardStep step = new WizardStep(); 
//... Customize here... 
Wizard1.WizardSteps.Add(step);
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

When using dynamic controls in ASP.Net, you need to add them to the control tree on *every* page load. There is a great set of articles on this whole process on the [Infinities Loop blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx).

A simpler approach might be to have all your wizard controls in your markup, but dynamically hide and show them, rather than dynamically create them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the steps in the oninit. I would recommend inheriting from user control and modifying the oninit to programitacally add the steps to a wizard declared in the control.